# How to use the pipeline redirection operator?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dll, command-line, cmd

**I'm LEARNING!**

The only problem is, I can't seem to get the pipeline redirection operator working. May seem a dumb question.

As all of you know, the pipeline operator retrieves output of first command as input of other command. How can I do what the pipeline operator is supposed to do?

Full code (Don't worry, It's very tiny):

```
@echo off
title malhunt e-alpha
echo starting...
if exist dlls.txt del dlls.txt
echo done verifying.
echo grabbing dlls...
for /f %%a in ('tasklist /m') do echo %%a >>dlls.txt
type dlls.txt
echo dll grabbing done
pause
for /f %%b in (dlls.txt) do findstr wow.dll, dlls.txt
pause
```

Simple enough, the line is

```
findstr wow.dll, dlls.txt|echo *
```

so now, I can tell that the problem occurs on `echo *` How exactly do you make `echo` create output of `findstr` input?

**NOTES**

The comma on the end of `wow.dll` is intentional, because `tasklist /m` likes to leave commas before the dynamic link libraries. I know that probably there's no `wow.dll` on the tasklist, but for future reference, how can I create pipeline redirection?

Answer (score 0):

- Including the comma to search the dll will fail if the dll is the last one in the list of modules loaded into a process.
- You can not pipe into `echo` command. Echo does not consume data from a pipe or a redirection.
- You don't need to pipe into `echo` command, `findstr /c:" wow.dll" dlls.txt` will show the result on console

Comment: Does it show the result if no such string is found?

Comment: @EpicTonic, no. I think we are discussing about your solution instead of about your problem. What do you need? to know that the dll is loaded? to know that the dll is not loaded? to know which module has it loaded? ... What output are you searching?

Comment: To know if a certain DLL has been loaded, say known malicious DLLs

Comment: @EpicTonic, `tasklist /m wow.dll | find /i "wow.dll" >nul && echo found || echo not found` This pipes the output of tasklist to find command to test if the dll name is in the output (which is later discarded). If there is no errorlevel in find command (found), the code after `&&` is executed. If there is a errorlevel, the code after `||` is executed.

Comment: I see. Trying that.tommorow